# Is it possible to upload properties file to aws parameter store and fetch one element in the file based on a key?

Tags: aws-sdk, spring-cloud-config, aws-ssm

In spring-cloud-config, it is possible to configure a properties file and then fetch an element in the properties file using the key.

But in aws parameter store, each key value is stored as a separate entry. As i understand, i need to take each key-value from the properties file and then configure in parameter store.

In reality, each region (DEV, QA etc.) has a set of configuration files. Each configuration file has a set of properties in it. These files can be grouped based on the hierarchy support that parameter store provides.

SDLC REGION >> FILE >> KEY-VALUE ENTRIES

SDLC region can be supported by hierarchy. Key-value entries are supported by parameter store. How do we manage the FILE entity in parameter store?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the path hierarchy and get parameters by path or by name prefix.

e.g.

SDLC_REGION/FILE/param1

SDLC_REGION/FILE/param2

SDLC_REGION2/FILE/param1

SDLC_REGION2/FILE/param2

then you can get by path: /SDLC_REGION/FILE  to get all it parameters

another option is using tags